# Include files from context differents How do I include an HTML file in my JSP file when the HTML file is located within a different servlet context?

Tags: java, servlets, struts

I have a relative path to another context on the same server

I can't  use `<jsp:include .../>` nor the `<%@ include .../>` directive are meant to be used with URL that are relative to the context

When i try `<c:import url="/dir/file.html" context="/context" var="tfile" scope="page"/>
  ${tfile}` needs an absolute url 
i get the `c:/dirExternal/dir/jsp/mainjsp.jsp` is not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code in your jsp to include html file form different context

```
    <@:include file="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/index.html" />
```

**OR you can do like given below to..**

1. access different context of same server

   `javax.servlet.ServletContext context = application.getContext("WAR Name");`
2. now access pages

   `javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
      rd.include(request, response);`
3. and last one entry in TOMCAT location conf/server.xml

   `<context path="/WAR Name" debug="0" reloadable="true" crosscontext="true">`